# internet connection problem on oracle virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, oracle

I installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 on Oracle 5.2.2. Everything was fine until I installed ROS and Gazebo packages. Now I can't surf the internet. I tried a lot of solutions suggested on the internet but it is still not working

With the NAT option, I can't ping the IP address or google.com and I can't surf using Firefox. With bridged network, I can ping IP address but can't do the same with google.com.

Can tell me possible reasons why this happens? I have been stuck for almost 2 weeks for now. ifconfig results as below, the results are written manually so there are some typos.

```
    enps03  link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:59:76:0e
            inet addr:10:0:2:15 Bcast 10:0:0:225 Mask:255:255:255:0
            inet6 addr: fe80:21e7:2f2b:39b7:cdf/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 METRIC:1
            RX packetsL:176 error:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:7072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueulen:1000
            RX bytes:11090 (11.0kb) TX byteds:548621 (548.6kb)

    lo      link encap:Local Loopback
            inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255:0:0:0
            inet6 addr: 1/128 Scope:Host
            UP LOOPBACK RUNING MULTICAST MTU:65536 METRIC:1
            RX packetsL:3600 error:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:3600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueulen:1000
            RX bytes:231068 (231.0 kb) TX bytes:231068 (231.0 kb)
```